# css: margin 0 auto working in IE8 but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

My css is [here (Fiddle Link)](http://jsfiddle.net/wybgfpfL/).

```
<div id="yearDiv">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


#yearDiv{

    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
}

#yearDiv ul{

    margin: 0 auto;

}

#yearDiv li{

    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px auto;
    display: block;

}

#yearDiv li a{

    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color:#a30f0f;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    background: #eee;
    border-color: #7C1D1B #711C17 #6A1F1C #7C1D1B;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-family: Courier New;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;

}

#yearDiv li a:LINK, #yearDiv li a:VISITED {



}

#yearDiv li a:HOVER, #yearDiv li a:ACTIVE {



}
```

On IE 8 it is rendered as this

[image]

whereas on chrome it is rendered as

[image]

It seems to me that margin left is not working.
I want to know how to get the links inside the div without leaving that much margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this-

```
#yearDiv ul{

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4aespjpf/1/)**

Comment: Nice solution. +1. I would mention though, that you also removed the `width` of the `a` elements for this to work. An important change.

Comment: I'm not judging but I guess anyone with 57k reputation doesn't need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the margin is not working, is because the `ul` and `li` elements don't have a specified width.

The easiest (and I think best) solution, is to move the `width` property from the `a` element to the `ul` element.

Also, you should remove the padding from the `ul`. So the css for the ul becomes:

```
#yearDiv ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
```

The `width` is removed from the `a` elements. Result is: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wybgfpfL/18/)

NB: I though you wanted the 'buttons' to be fixed width, centered in the variable width `div`. Seeing Maddy's answer, I think I might be wrong in this assumption. Anyway, I hope this answer still helps you understand what the issue was, regardless of the solution you will use in the end.

My solution: give the `ul` a fixed width so `margin: 0 auto` will work for centering it. Maddy's solution: Don't specify a width for `ul`, `li` and `a` at all; give the `div` a padding and let the (block styled) elements just fill the available space. In either case, you shouldn't specify a width for the `li` and `a` elements.